# listFiles() is of no use from Android 10(scoped storage). Need files of particular directory

Tags: android, file, android-studio, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I have implemented scoped storage & need to list the JPEG files from a third party app let's name it Test app which creates 'test' folder in following two path

1. In Internal storage -> /storage/emulated/0/Test/.images
2. In sdcard -> /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.app.test/files/Test/.images

In redmi K20pro running on Android 10 returns ArrayList on .listFiles irrespective of scoped storage.

However Nokia 6.1 running on Android 10 returns null if scoped storage is enabled & null on scoped storage enabled

Please help me the to fetch files from these 2 folders.

Comment: new File(path).listFiles() will do the listing if you supply a valid full path to a directory.

Comment: After implementing scoped storage, from Android 10 files api is of no use

Comment: You can very well use it for getFilesDir, getExternalFilesDir and getExternalFilesDirs. It looks as if your second one is included.

Comment: pls check the updated post @blackapps

Comment: Your number 1 will not work on Q if you do not add legacyExternalStorage to manifest file. Your second one equals getExternalFilesDir or the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs. Very strange that you did not mention their respective paths.

Comment: I'm setting legacyExternalStorage=false, scoped storage enabled . I have mentioned the path right Test is a third party app, which creates folder in these path & I need to access the above mentioned path in my app.
1. needs to be accessed with SAF.
2. Cannot be accessed

Comment: "I'm setting legacyExternalStorage=false, scoped storage enabled" -- then you are not supposed to have filesystem-level access to those locations on Android 10+. "1. needs to be accessed with SAF" -- correct. "2. Cannot be accessed" -- that should still be selectable with SAF on Android 10, though you will lose access to it on Android 11.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to use `listFiles()` files on Android 10 as follows:

Add this permission to your project's AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In this file, add the flag `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` under your `<application>` tag.

Request the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission from your user:

```
int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
}
```

Optionally, handle the result of the request:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, Do the you need to do.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "permission was granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                // permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use `listFiles()`, for example to list the files in the phone's download dir:

```
File[] files = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles();
Log.i(getClass().getName(), "fileList = " + Arrays.toString(files));
```

Comment: This no longer works on Android 11+

Answer (score 0):

it is maybe a bit late, but these 2 websites helped me:

[Developer Privacy Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

[Developer manage all files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files)

You have to request the permission separately from the user to access it as with Android 9 and lower.

Hoped it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Mediastore way` for getting the image files from specific directory.

You need to pass the path of the directory with its parent directory.

```
private void loadImagesFromDir(Context context, String targetFolderPath) {
        File targetFolder = new File(targetFolderPath);

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED
        };

        String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ? ";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + targetFolder.getParentFile().getName() + "/" + targetFolder.getName() + "%"};
        String selectionOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, selectionOrder
        );

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                String filePath =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
                long dateAdded =
                        cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```